# WooCommerce payment class: init hook not fired in __construct

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm tearing my hair out on this one, because all of the examples I've seen appear to be doing exactly what I'm doing... yet no matter what I do, my `add_action('init')` hook isn't firing.

In the smallest, most concise example, my payment gateway plugin looks like this:

```
function vnmTestPay_init() {

    if (!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) {
        return;
    }

    class WC_Gateway_Test_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        public function init() {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            new $class;
        }

        public function __construct() {

            add_action('init', array($this, 'process_web_hooks'));

        }

        public static function process_web_hooks() {

            if (!is_admin()) {
                //    In reality, process some $_GET vars and JSON, but for testing...

                die('INIT!');
            }
        }
    }

    //  Add the gateway to WC

    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'vnmTestPay_addGateway');
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'vnmTestPay_init', 0);

//  Add the Gateway to WooCommerce

function vnmTestPay_addGateway($methods) {

    if (!in_array('WC_Gateway_Test_Gateway', $methods)) {
        $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Test_Gateway';
    }

    return $methods;
}
```

I want to hook into WP's `init` so I can process incoming webhooks (with expected `$_GET` parameters and a JSON body of code) as they get sent by the payment provider several times throughout the day. In this instance I just threw in a `die()` so I could see it working when visiting the homepage of the site, but no dice.

I based this on an older payment plugin of mine which *did* trigger the `init` hook correctly but only because, after instantiating the class, I threw in this line:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', array('WC_Gateway_Test_Gateway', 'init'));
```

...which actually resulted in a some hooks being triggered twice; so I would guess this is *not* the way to do it.

Any ideas on where I'm tripping up?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you can't use `$this` with a static method. Not sure how to use the array with a static method. Not tested but you could try `self` or make the method non static.